# Will my project in xcode 4.3 be affected if I download 4.4?

Tags: ios, xcode

I never got around to updating my version of xcode. Will my current projects still work fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**They'lll still work fine.** The newer version of XCode has no problem working with older projects.